Use of Possessive Apostrophes in Titles
When referring to our Visitors Entrance or in a document, do I need an apostrophe following Visitors' because it is a title?

You will see it without but the standard is with it. On a sign, most likely without.

Such labels, especially when in capitals and on signs, often drop apostrophes. But there is also a move to more generally drop associative rather than strictly possessive (in the ownership, John's bike, or 'has as part of', His car's offside rear tyre, usages) apostrophes. Thus writers guilds, travellers cheques, working mens clubs. See Is it correct to say'I write children books' (not possessive case)?.

There are several related questions: couples' dance and clothes closet, hotel room, etc.
